# Class type including static methods

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I need to create a function which will accept some base class as argument and return other class extending base class.

I tried the following implementation:

```
interface Constructable<T> {
   new (...args: any[]): T;
}

function getClass<T>(_class: Constructable<T>): Constructable<T> {
  // in real app there will be some logic to return different class which extends _class
  return _class;
}
```

but it doesn't allow me to call static methods of returned class:

```
class Class {
  static staticMethod() {}
  instanceMethod() {}
}

const _class = getClass(Class);
_class.staticMethod(); // Property staticMethod does not exist on type Constructable<Class>
```

(err: `staticMethod does not exist on type Constructable<Class>`)

How should I modify this function signature so that it'll work as follow?

```
const _class = getClass(Class);

_class.instanceMethod();          // should not be possible
new _class().instanceMethod();    // should be ok
_class.staticMethod();            // should be ok
```

sandbox: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-cbhp63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the whole class type in the generic parameter. The generic type parameter can be constrained to be a constructor. When it will be inferred the generic type parameter will be the whole class including the static methods:

```
interface Constructable<T> {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}

function getClass<T extends Constructable<any>>(_class: T) {
     // in real app there will be some logic to return different class which extends _class
    return class extends _class {
        addedMethod() { }
        static addedStaticMethod() {}
    };
}

class Class {
    static staticMethod() {}
    instanceMethod() {}
}

const _class = getClass(Class);
_class.staticMethod(); 
_class.addedStaticMethod();
new _class().addedMethod();
new _class().instanceMethod();
```

**Note**: if you need the instance type you can use `InstanceType<T>`